# Printing a float value in python not rounding up

Tags: python

I have to print a number in python of this form :
 n = "35.66667"
The output should be "35.666". Now, I tried round() function in python upto 3 decimal places but its giving me incorrect result of 35.667.

Any idea how can i print **the float value upto 3 decimal places without rounding up**?

Comment: Why would the output need to be `35.666`? That's not an accurate reflection of the value.

Comment: Yes, but thats the question asked. To print the float value upto 3 decimal places without rounding up

Comment: You wish to trim the string representation to 3 places, not to round the number.

Comment: @AgniswarBakshi: then trim the string to your desired size. Not sure why you'd want to do this in the first place however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Yes, but that's the question asked. To print the float value upto 3 decimal places without rounding up.

So trim the string representation:

```
def trim_float(n, d):
    n_str = str(n)
    point_index = n_str.find('.')
    return float(n_str[:point_index + d + 1])

print(trim_float(35.66667, 3))
>> 35.666
```

Answer (score 1):

in academic circumstances, the answer might be e.g.:

*"convert the string to a float, `math.floor` it to 3 decimal places and convert to back to string"*

in the real life (or on an interview to any company you WANT to work for), the correct answer is:

**"Why?!? Please explain the reasoning behind this business logic before we attempt any implementation."**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to coerce 35.66667 to 35.666 (i.e. round down), this could work:

```
import math

n = 35.6667

print(math.floor(n * 1000) / 1000)
```

**Output**

```
35.666
```

Hopefully someone else can post a more elegant way to accomplish this, though.

Answer (score 0):

Using `format`:

```
n = 35.66667
print "{0!s:.6}".format(n)
# 35.666
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you want to truncate the everything past the third decimal. Round up gives you the correct rounded result, but not what you need.

You could just slice the unwanted decimals.

```
n = "35.66667"
print(float(n[:-2]))
=> 35.666
```